# Jquery, Ajax save to database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am trying to create a simple attendance register for a kids club, when they turn up for a practice session they need to record who's paid on the night. It's more or less works as I want it to, but I'm struggling with the last bit.

When I click on the button to add a user_id to the paid table, along with the date and and status, it does as expected, so all good there. However, I would like the button to change icons based on Paid status, which I can do buy reading a database value -

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-status" id="<?php echo $row['user_id']; ?>" data-status="<?php echo $row['status']; ?>" title="Active/Deactive details" >
<?php if(empty($row['status'])){ ?>
    <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<?php }else{ ?>
    <i class="fa fa-ban" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<?php } ?>
```

On button click the following jQuery handles the post event -

```
    $(document).on('click', '.btn-status', function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
    var btn_button = $(this);
    var status = 1;
    btn_button.html(' <i class="fa fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> ');
    var tbl_id = $(this).attr("id");
    var tbl_status = $(this).data("status");
    if(tbl_status == 0) status = 1;
    else status = 0;

    $.post('save_details.php', { form_name: "user_status", tbl_id: tbl_id, status: status }, function(data,status){
        console.log(data);
        if(data == "1"){
            $('.warning-modal-message').html("Record status changed successfully.");
            $('#warningModal').modal('show');
            setTimeout(function(){  location.reload(); }, 2000);
        }
        else{
            $('.warning-modal-message').html("Data deletion failed.");
        }
    });
});
```

And the PHP for the database -

```
    if($form_name == "user_status"){
    $tbl_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['tbl_id']);
    $status = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['status']);

    $query = "insert into attendance(rider_id, at_status, at_date) values('$tbl_id','$status',NOW())";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    if($result)
        echo "1";
    else
        echo "0";
}
```

The problem I'm having is the the query relies on the status field in the user data table to control which icon is visible. What I need is a way to have all the icons set to fa-ban icon on page reload and the thumb icon when the button is pressed to take attendance.

I have tries setting the `$row['status'];` to 1 manually, I have tried Bootstrap Toggle Switch, Bootstrap Toggle Button and loads of articles on here but I'm not having any luck

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It's awful and has been removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Make **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will end up with severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working more or less as needed using Bootstrap Toggle Switch -

```
<input type="checkbox" id="<?php echo $row['user_id']; ?>" class="toggleBtn" name="toggleBtn" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Paid Fees" data-off="Unpaid" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger" data-size="small" >
```

Using the following jQuery -

```
    $(document).on('change', '.toggleBtn', function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();

    // Disable switch on click to help prevent multiple submit
    $(this).bootstrapToggle('disable');

    //var btn_button = $(this);
    var status = $(this).prop('checked');
    //btn_button.html(' <i class="fa fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> ');
    var tbl_id = $(this).attr("id");
    var tbl_status = $(this).data("status");
    //if(tbl_status == 0) status = 1;
    //else status = 0;

    $.post('save_details.php', { form_name: "user_status", tbl_id: tbl_id, status: status }, function(data,status){
        console.log(data);
        if(status == "checked"){
            $('.warning-modal-message').html("Record status changed successfully.");
            $('#warningModal').modal('show');
            setTimeout(function(){  location.reload(); }, 2000);
        }
        else{
            $('.warning-modal-message').html("Data deletion failed.");
        }
    });
});
```

And the following PHP -

```
if($form_name == "user_status"){
    $tbl_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['tbl_id']);
    $status = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['status']);

    //SELECT * FROM `attendance` WHERE `rider_id` = 1 AND `at_date` = DATE(NOW())

    $result = "SELECT * FROM `attendance` WHERE `rider_id` = '$tbl_id' AND `at_date` = DATE(NOW())";
    $total = ($result);

    if($total==0){
        $query = "insert into attendance(rider_id, at_status, at_date) values('$tbl_id','$status',NOW())";
        $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    }

    //$query = "insert into attendance(rider_id, at_status, at_date) values('$tbl_id','$status',NOW())";
    //$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    //if($result)
        //echo "1";
    //else
        //echo "0";
}
```

A couple of the issues I'm having now is that the warnings are not showing up and the $qry to check if a rider has already been entered on the day (the switches are reset on page refresh!

```
    if(status == "checked"){
    $('.warning-modal-message').html("Record status changed successfully.");
    $('#warningModal').modal('show');
    setTimeout(function(){  location.reload(); }, 2000);
}
else{
    $('.warning-modal-message').html("Data deletion failed.");
}
```

Thanks!